# Is there a way to append a list with the same item, if the same item appears twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to build a complex hangman game in Python for a school assignment (first post on here btw, so sorry if I don't use the correct etiquette).  My code so far is operating on a basic, but functional level; I have a generated file filled with random word variation.  I import the file, put it into a list, clean the data and use random to randomly select a word.  The program repeatedly asks the user to input a letter or word until they guess correctly or run out of lives.  I have ran into an issue where if the same letter appears multiple times in a word, it won't register the fact that it needs to scan and append the list twice for each time the word appears.  This might be a really simple problem, but I appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance!

(P.S. underscores is the list that displays underscores in place of unidentified letters for the output)

```
elif guess in correctLetters:
print("\nYou got a letter! Here is where it appears in the word:\n")
index = word.index(guess)
underscores[index] = guess
for i in underscores:
 print(i, end="")
```

In terms of an example, I want the code to use the user's input ('guess') and see if it appears in the list 'correctLetters'.  If it does, I want the code to append 'guess' into the correct index in the list.  E.g. if the unknown word is 'hangman' and ('guess') is 'h', the code will append 'h' into the correct position in the list and then just make the list look more pleasing to the eye.  My current problem is (following the example outlined above) if I were to enter 'a' I want the code to return '_ a _ _ _ a *' where as now it will only return '* a _ _ _ _ _'.  I need the code to see that the same item appears twice in the list and so it appends it twice as well in the list that will be shown to the user.  Hope this makes my issue clearer.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: It is not easy to understand what is your issue here. Could you provide a minimal example, with the result it gives and what you would expect instead?

Answer (score 1):

You might think about going through your hidden word letter for letter and construct a display version of it revealing guessed letters or hiding unguessed letters. Maybe like:

```
guesses = set()
word = "hello"

## each round make a guess...
guess = "l"
guesses.add(guess)

letters_underscored = [
    letter if letter in guesses else "_"
    for letter in word
]

word_underscored = "".join(letters_underscored)
print(word_underscored)
```

This will give you:

```
__ll_
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question:

```
index = word.index(guess)
underscores[index] = guess
```

...finds the first occurrence of the letter in the word and replaces the underscore with the guess. A simple way to replace all occurrences would be to loop until `word.index(guess)` raises an exception, ignoring indices that have already been replaced by using the second argument of the `index` method, which specifies a starting point for the search. E.g.:

```
index = -1
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        index = word.index(guess, index + 1) # find the index of guess in word that occurs after `index + 1`
        underscores[index] = guess
    except ValueError:
        # if all occurrences have been replaced, stop
        done = True
```